# Rewrite nested foreach with linq if there are some operations apart from internal foreach loops

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code and would like to translate it to linq. Is it possible, considering the two foreach loops inside the external foreach? Currently I could only translate the internal foreach loops to linq but still code is so long that I think that it might be shorter.

```
List<complexType> listOfComplex = ...some list...
List<complexType> newListOfCOmplex = new List<complexType>();
SomeObjectType someObject = ...some object...

foreach(var cT in listOfComplex)
{
    var someObjectPropertyValue = someObject.property.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.value == smth);

    if(someObjectPropertyValue == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var t = someObjectPropertyValue.Something.AnotherSomethin;

    if(t==null)
    {
        newListOfCOmplex.Add(cT);
        continue;
    }

    var collectionFirst = t.Where(s=>s.value == firstValue);

    foreach (var f in collectionFirst)
    {
        someOtherMethod(f);
    }
    newListOfCOmplex.Add(cT);

    var collectionSecond = t.Where(s=>s.value == secondValue);

    foreach (var s in collectionSecond)
    {
        someOtherMethod(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you really mean `FirstOrDefault(a=>a.value = smth);` or should that be `==`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole code is quite suspicious as variable `cT` is only added to List, neither of it`s properties is checked inside foreach loop.

Either this is original behaviour or consequence of obfuscation, you should revise your sample.

As for current sample better way to handle loop will be

```
List<complexType> listOfComplex = ...some list...
//List<complexType> newListOfCOmplex = new List<complexType>();
SomeObjectType someObject = ...some object...

//Totaly unneccessary as newListOfCOmplex is complete copy of listOfComplex 
//foreach(var cT in listOfComplex)
//{
//  newListOfCOmplex.Add(cT);
//}    

var someObjectPropertyValue = someObject.property.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.value == smth) ?? return null;

var t = someObjectPropertyValue.Something.AnotherSomethin ?? return smth;

var collection = t.Where(s=>(s.value == firstValue || s.value == secondValue) ).ToList();
foreach (var f in collection) someOtherMethod(f);

return smth;
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding each component would be better to `newListOfComplex = new List<complexType>(listOfComplex);` and you don't need to use `collection` just `foreach` over `t.Where...`, in fact we could just replace the whole foreach action set up by coalescing, minutely slower but much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for revision, in this particular case even `newListOfCOmplex` is unneccessary as it is complete copy of `listOfComplex`. Provided sample gets even stranger. Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: @Nogard Hm, if I'm not reading it wrong, if firstValue == secondValue, your code calls someOtherMethod half as many times as the original.

Comment: Indeed, although from the sample it seems that value should be distinct. If it's not the case, than better solution is to create small supplimentary function to shorten such kind of iteration. Ie:  

`private void Func(object t, string Value)  
{  
     var collection = t.Where( s=>s.value == Value );  
     foreach (var f in collection) someOtherMethod(f);  
}`

Answer (score 0):

To build on my comments to Nogard one could do it like so:

```
newListOfComplex = listOfComplex.ToList();

var stream = someObject.property
                       .Where(a => a.value == smth)
                       .Select(a => a.Something.AnotherSomething)
                       .FirstOrDefault() ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()
if(stream.Any())
{
    foreach( var f in stream.Where(s=> s.value == firstValue)
                            .Concat(stream.Where(s => s.value == secondValue)))
    someOtherMethod(f);
    return smth;
}
else return null;
```

Comment: LINQ in foreach condition is very bad for perfomance as it will be queried once per each subitem. Depending on `s` it could reduce speed in times.

Comment: @Nogard  in this case not as FirstOrDefault is eager executed so it is has already executed and cached the query, however if you mean you should construct an ienumerable before foreach then that's just plain wrong, GetEnunerator is called once in either case they will be identical.... For iqueryable you can make an argument due to latency on the connection, but as mentioned previously it's already been queried...

Comment: I meant `foreach( var f in stream.Where(...)` part. During Foreach iterated collection should stay unmodified. Thus, Every Foreach iteration (particaly .MoveNext()) checks whether its true. Only way to do this is to re-query collection.

Comment: @Nogard If we are talking `LinqToObject` then this is certainly not true, and if we are talking `LinqToDatabase` then this is provider dependent, and all the providers I know `yield return` on the datareader, hence query once but pull data back when requested, so again it would not act as you think it would. But in any case for this `FirstOrDefault` is eager evaluated so it has already cached the object and hence there is no difference in declaring an enumerable outside or inside the foreach loop...

Comment: Let me clear my point. `stream` indeed is cached but its subset used in foreach is not. Thus, subset `stream.Where(s=> s.value == firstValue).Concat(stream.Where(s => s.value == secondValue))` will we evaluated each time to assure its consistency.

Comment: @Nogard I think we are talking on different points here. If you declare an `IEnumerable<T>` outside the foreach which is not eager evaluated then it has no difference than declaring it in the foreach. I have done a quick benchmark on this which confirms this. If you execute your query and then foreach it, it will be significantly slower as it is enumerating the `subset` as you called it, then enumerating over it again, again have confirmed this with a benchmark. I think you need to go over the whole concept of an enumerable again...

Comment: Sadly speaking you are wrong. Please test following sample I wrote: [PasteBin sample program](http://pastebin.com/aHhjkHDb)  Pay additional attention to `.ToList()` as this is key feature in speeding LINQ (which is lazy query and for sure without .ToList() there won't be difference between two methods). Results of concrete program can be found at the bottom of the pastebin

Comment: @Nogard Sadly speaking you are talking about a point not inherent in the OP question as the `subset` is only enumerated over once. I agree if you are using the same enumerable over and over then it is a good idea to cache it (as demonstrated by your example) so finally we are on the same page. Note: `ToList` is fairly heavy for just caching the data, why not just construct a single linked list? And why do you call `ToList()` inside the `foreach`? that is redundant and significantly adds to the execution time.

Comment: @Nogard Also for benchmarking please use a more accurate timer like `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`. As you have agreed with the deferred execution being the same, my only other point was caching then enumerating was ineffecient, so to benchmark this you need to move the `ToList()` inside your `for` loop, which you will find is equivalent to `ToList()` in the `foreach` and is much slower than just enumerating.

Comment: Without .ToList() first sample gives me `Difference: 00:00:07.0217021` which is approx the same (in fact little slower) as with it.

Comment: unattended submit in previous comment... Without .ToList() first sample gives me `Difference: 00:00:07.0217021` which is approx the same (in fact little slower) as with it.  PLease provide your sample where `caching then enumerating was ineffecient`, as .ToList( in my second part of program) does exactly this and boosts enumeration in approx 9 times.

Comment: @Nogard http://pastebin.com/5DRuLBqK so `caching then enumerating` corresponds to `DeclaredOutside2`

Comment: thanks for your sample, just one rectification. As `var declaredOutside = baseEnumerable.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).ToList();` in `DeclaredOutside1` and `DeclaredOutside2` is independent from `for` loop, try to move it outside. duration of `DeclaredOutside1` will be same (LINQ is delayed till `foreach`) but duration of  `DeclaredOutside2` will be twice lower (LINQ is triggered by `.ToList()`). Thus you gain perfomance boost not altering logic at all. But of course this is valid if only LINQ query is independent from `for` loop.

Comment: @Nogard that was my original point, I already agreed that if you are using an Enumerable over and over it is useful to cache outside of the logic, you seemed to be disagreeing with the statement that repeated caching was inefficient (my second point) which is precisely not moving the `ToList()` outside of the for loop. So back to the OP question, as the enumerable is only consumed once it is inefficient to cache then consume the cache, as demonstrated.